# htaccess redirction from www to non-www url with ssl certification

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

i would like to redirect my site form **www** to **non-www url** with ssl certificate.
i have write the code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://\%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

that works but if url have any get request it'll get redirect to the home page.

Comment: Where is the connection to `php` as suggested by the tags you chose?

Comment: Do not test your rewriterules with `[R=301]`. This will create a **permanent** redirect and browsers cache these kind of redirects. If you permanently redirect a to b, the browser will cache this and on a next attempt to get a, the browser will not ask the server for a, but instead loads b immedeatelly. Needless to say, the browser is therefore unaware of changes you have made to your rewrite rule in case it didn't work as you expected. Use `[R]` instead (temporary redirect) until all your rewriterules do exactly what you want them to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$1` does not resolve to any value until you caputure some value in your `RewiteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

PS: I made some additional minor modifications.

Comment: `^/` in PerDirectory context (like .htaccess) will not match any request. It should be `^(.*)$`. I am not 100% sure if `\%1` is correct here.

Comment: Sorry, my fault: indeed I did not realize that we are talking about stupid `.htaccess` files here. Thanks for the hint, I fixed that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Redirect www urls to non-www**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**OR** Alternative code that you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Reference site](http://dhavalbharadva.blogspot.in/2013/05/force-users-to-use-www-or-non-www-of.html)

Comment: @Sumurai8 may i know how?

Comment: You only need one rule, and the second rule included `http://` at the time of writing.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i have updated my answer, http:// written by mistake. thanks for your suggestion.